# Sub specific character in R

Tags: r

In R, how do I sub specific character from my data?

I have this :

20220801_NM7_Chrom_2399_A12_CCIH.CSV

I want get below

20220801_NM7_Chrom_2399_CCIH

Thanks for sparing your time.

Comment: It looks like you are wanting to do two things: remove the ".CSV" and also the "_A12", which presumably varies with different strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can try this

```
x <- "20220801_NM7_Chrom_2399_A12_CCIH.CSV"

sub( "_A\\d+_" , "_", sub("\\..*" , "" , x))
```

- Output

```
"20220801_NM7_Chrom_2399_CCIH"
```

Comment: I like this, but it wouldn't work if the "A12" can take the value "B42", etc.

Comment: You can use `sub( "_[A-Z]\\d+_" , "_", sub("\\..*" , "" , x))`